# Visua studio, proyecto winforms en c#: Problema con formularios secundarios con formato formborderstyle a fixedsingle

Tags: c#, windows-forms

En visual studio tengo:

- Un proyecto winforms en c# con un formulario mdi.
- El formulario MDI tiene un menustrip desde donde llamo a los formularios secundarios con formborderstyle a fixedsingle.
  El problema que tengo en mi caso, es que los formularios secundarios no cogen el formato fixedsingle cuando le asigno como padre el formulario mdi, mantienen el formato sizable:

  ```
    private void nuevoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 newMDIChild = new Form2();
        // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
        newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
        // Display the new form.
        newMDIChild.Show();
    }
  ```

Si no realizo la asignación
newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
entonces sí me visualiza los formularios con el formato asignado. ¿alguna solución para este problema?.

Otra cosa que he probado, ha sido asignarles el formato desde código, antes de la llamada show y/o en la función load de los formularios hijos, pero tampoco ha funcionado:

```
    private void nuevoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 newMDIChild = new Form2();
        // Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
        newMDIChild.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
        // Display the new form.
        newMDIChild.Show();
    }
```

Por supuesto, revisado formulario MDI para que sea mdicontainer.
Gracias de antemano.